# Adding controls inline with simple_form, nested_form and Twitter Bootstrap in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I'm using simple_form, nested_form and Twitter Bootstrap and trying to put the "Remove Link" from nested_form on the same line as the object.

Right now it looks like this:

http://grab.by/eKDS

and I want it to look like this:

http://grab.by/eKEc

Here's what my code looks like:

```
<%= cform.simple_fields_for :licensings do |lf| %>
  <%= lf.input :state, :collection => us_states, :wrapper => false %>
  <%= lf.link_to_remove "Remove this Licensing", :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-danger' %>
<% end %>
```

I've tried putting the second link_to_remove inside a block for the first lf.input but then the actual dropdown doesn't appear.  I've looked through simple_form's code but I wasn't able to track down if there was a way to accomplish this.

Comment: How about wrapping each in a div and using CSS to handle the positioning.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks for the answers but I couldn't get either to work.  I found the answer on the Google Groups mailing list:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/plataformatec-simpleform/hL9ek5svyAU

```
  <%= cform.simple_fields_for :licensings do |lf| %>
    <%= lf.input :state do %>
      <%= lf.input_field :state, :collection => us_states  %>
      <%= lf.link_to_remove "Remove this Licensing", :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-danger' %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to add the class "inline" to your nested form?

```
<%= form_for @test, :html => { :class => 'form-inline' } do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :some_field, :class => 'text_field' %>
  <%= f.submit "Save", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes, but this is about inlining one particular set of controls, not the entire form.  For the form I have form-horizontal already.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form), you can create your custom wrapper. You must to add something like this in you simple_form's initializer :

```
config.wrappers :inline do |b|
  b.use :placeholder
  b.use :label_input
end
```

And use it like this :

```
<%= cform.simple_fields_for :licensings do |lf| %>
  <%= lf.input :state, :collection => us_states, :wrapper => inline %>
  <%= lf.link_to_remove "Remove this Licensing", :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-danger' %>
<% end %>
```